# How to display error word at progressed Broadcast Upload Extension(iOS, replaykit)

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I stuck in a little problem.

I exercised broadcast upload extension with replaykit,

I wanted display a error code when occured exceptions.

But I couldn't any way for that.

Would you teach me a way?

[image]

I hate (null) and want to replace other word.

Comment: I bet here should be some code shown...

Answer (score 1):

Use finishBroadcastWithError, NSError must be use 'NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey' to describe.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this issue by this protocol

**finishBroadcastWithError()**

in RPBroadcast handler

for more refer [apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpbroadcastsamplehandler/2721526-finishbroadcastwitherror)

example:

```
let userInfo = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: "You have Stopped Screen Sharing"]
        finishBroadcastWithError(NSError(domain: "ScreenShare", code: -1, userInfo: userInfo))
```